# Hadoop Block Management

Tags: hadoop

I'm a beginner with Hadoop (I already followed several tutorials). I am currently researching the underlying replication model in Hadoop. I want to know how the model looks like and where I can find the code.

Interim results:
After researching the packages of Hadoop, I came to find the package "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement". Here I found several classes like BlockManager.java. But I have come to a dead end.

Can you give me any reference to a website/book where I can find the underlying replication model in Hadoop. Is there any? If not, what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

There's a high level overview in the HDFS architecture guide:

- http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/hdfs_design.html#Data+Replication

As for tracing the source, the NameNode will instruct a DataNode to transfer a block to other DataNodes. You can trace this command in the DataNode source at the following method:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.processCommand(DatanodeCommand[])
 -> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.processCommand(DatanodeCommand)
     See the DatanodeProtocol.DNA_TRANSFER command type in the switch
   -> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.transferBlocks(Block[], DatanodeInfo[][])
     -> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.transferBlock(Block, DatanodeInfo[])
```

You can work backwards from the command being issued in NameNode:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DatanodeDescriptor.getReplicationCommand(int)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.handleHeartbeat(DatanodeRegistration, long, long, long, int, int)
```

From here you'll need to trace the `pendingReplications` and `neededReplications` instance variables

Comment: Thank you for your time answering my question. I will look to it. :D